# how to define tr, td, label styles in material table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hi I am now using material table in react.

here: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling, we can use `cellStyle, headerStyle`, but what if I want to define more details, like styles of `<tr> <td>` of the cell, add `<label>` to the cell conent, how can we do that?

Answer (score 1):

`<tr>` is table row, so you can use **options.rowStyle**.
`<td>`is table cell, so you can use **column.cellStyle**.

If you want specific styles to some cells, you can pass React or html elements to the `data`:

```
data={[
  { name: <div><h1>Baran</h1>aaa</div> },
  { name: <MyStyledCellWithMultipleElements name="Joe" /> }
]}
```

Comment: how about text? for example add a <label></label> to the cell content?

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if this is what you need

Comment: so do you mean if I want to apply styles to <td>, I need to put to columns definition, even if the <td> style should apply to every cell? and similarly,  i need to put <h1> to every data field, if I want to have <h1> for all fields?

Comment: You can create a separate component with desired style and pass it to every data field. If you data comes from backend as string, you can make a `.map` and change need string to a styled component that receives that string. This is in case if you need move elements in the cell.